# How to provide namespace with table in HbaseMapReduce Job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am creating a Map Reduce Jon using Hbase. So I am taking some input from a table in mapper job and then then I am using Reducer Job. To call the reducer Job I am using this function.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(table, reducer, job);
```

Here table is of Type String. My problem is that I need to use the table with namespace here and I do not know how to do that.

In case of mapper Job. Api is providing the function for NameSpace i.e.

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(table, scan, mapper, outputKeyClass, outputValueClass, job);
```

Here table is of Type org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.

So can anyone tell me how to do that in reducer job as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just need to provide the table name as

**namespace:tablename**

and it will handle it internally.

Answer (score 0):

I guss your want to use a mapreduce job to   read your hbase table and write some data to  hdfs ?  if so 
look here

```
    void org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob
    (String table, Scan scan, Class<? extends TableMapper> mapper, 
Class<?>     outputKeyClass,
     Class<?> outputValueClass, Job job, boolean addDependencyJars) throws IOException
```

this method could add your job (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;`) in the setting  .

```
job.setJarByClass(MapReduceReaderHbaseDriver.class);  

job.setReducerClass(WordCountHBaseReducer.class); 

 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfspath"));
```

use those  methods  could make the reducer get  connected  to hdfs

BTW  translate from one hbase table  to another hbase  table   you can use import  or  export  command

for example

```
  (1)old cluster：./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export test hdfs://new cluster ip:9000/dic/test
  (2)new cluster：./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import test hdfs://new cluster ip:9000/dic/test
```

Comment: i want to get data from one table and copy that data to another table after processing. those tables are in particular name space. so in reducer job how will i say that i want to write my data to this table having this namespace